# builtins.TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'settings'

Tags: python, scrapy

When I run my crawler that uses the scrapy framework, get a error:

```
Unhandled error in Deferred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 192, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 196, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "\python\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1656, in unwindGenerator    
    return _cancellableInlineCallbacks(gen)
  File "\python\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1571, in _cancellableInlineCallbacks
    _inlineCallbacks(None, g, status)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "\python\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1445, in _inlineCallbacks   
    result = current_context.run(g.send, result)
  File "\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 87, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 101, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\scraper.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 35, in from_settings
    mw = create_instance(mwcls, settings, crawler)
  File "\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 166, in create_instance
    instance = objcls.from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\pipelines\media.py", line 76, in from_crawler
    pipe = cls.from_settings(crawler.settings)
  File "\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\pipelines\files.py", line 368, in from_settings       
    return cls(store_uri, settings=settings)
builtins.TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'settings'
```

`settings` is only used in `scrapy.cfg`. I don't know where the problem is.
Here is `scrapy.cfg`.

```
[settings]
default = scrapy_name.settings

[deploy]
#url = http://localhost:6800/
project = scrapy_name
```

And here is my file structure .

```
└── my project
└── scrapy_name
├── data
├── spider
| ├── _init_.py
| └── my_spider.py
├── _init_.py
├── items.py
├── middlewares.py
├── pipelines.py
└── settings.py
```

[Steps to Reproduce]

1.`run scrapy crawl my_spider -s JOBDIR=crawls/my_spider-1` by setup.py. Or run `scrapy crawl my_spider` by cmd.

2.The browser windows appears. But it's only displayed as "New Tab Page".

3.Get the error.

[Versions]

Scrapy 2.5.0 - no active project

[Additional context]

I use selenium.webdriver to load page, i don't know if this has anything to do with the error.
I update the twisted and install splite3.

Comment: The problem has been solved. It seems that only one pipeline class can be added to ITEM_PIPELINES of settings.py. I use one pipeline class to process different data.